# Is there a way to capture a users data after a Paypal transaction has been completed?

Tags: html, php, paypal

Are there any $_POST variables that are sent with my transaction complete url, that I can save in the users session.  I would like to be able to capture the email address from the customers PayPal account.

Comment: "What I don't understand is how to get the data back from Pay Pal once they are redirected to my checkout complete page." - [Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is PayPal's message service that sends a notification when a transaction is affected.](https://www.paypal.com/ipn)

Comment: @danlefree I have edited the question, is this good enough to be opened?

Comment: Please review the [IPN PHP sample code](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt) and [IPN Documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNReference) - what you are asking is answered there.

Comment: @danlefree Hi, I am going to use my IPN to save to the database but I would like to pull this information from the database and display it back to the customer. I think I have found a solution. I guess I can save the users IP address to the database, and then search for this when they reach the transaction complete page on my site.